# TensorFlow example save mandelbrot image

Tags: tensorflow

Learning how to use tensorflow, first tutorial code on mandelbrot set below

```
# Import libraries for simulation
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Imports for visualization
import PIL.Image
from io import BytesIO
from IPython.display import Image, display

def DisplayFractal(a, fmt='jpeg'):
  """Display an array of iteration counts as a
     colorful picture of a fractal."""
  a_cyclic = (6.28*a/20.0).reshape(list(a.shape)+[1])
  img = np.concatenate([10+20*np.cos(a_cyclic),
                        30+50*np.sin(a_cyclic),
                        155-80*np.cos(a_cyclic)], 2)
  img[a==a.max()] = 0
  a = img
  a = np.uint8(np.clip(a, 0, 255))
  f = BytesIO()
  PIL.Image.fromarray(a).save(f, fmt)
  display(Image(data=f.getvalue()))


sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

# Use NumPy to create a 2D array of complex numbers

Y, X = np.mgrid[-1.3:1.3:0.005, -2:1:0.005]
Z = X+1j*Y

xs = tf.constant(Z.astype(np.complex64))
zs = tf.Variable(xs)
ns = tf.Variable(tf.zeros_like(xs, tf.float32))

tf.global_variables_initializer().run()


# Compute the new values of z: z^2 + x
zs_ = zs*zs + xs

# Have we diverged with this new value?
not_diverged = tf.abs(zs_) < 4

# Operation to update the zs and the iteration count.
#
# Note: We keep computing zs after they diverge! This
#       is very wasteful! There are better, if a little
#       less simple, ways to do this.
#
step = tf.group(
  zs.assign(zs_),
  ns.assign_add(tf.cast(not_diverged, tf.float32))
  )


for i in range(200): step.run()

DisplayFractal(ns.eval())
```

returns this on shell

```
<IPython.core.display.Image at 0x7fcdee1da810>
```

It doesn't display the image and I'd prefer if it saved the image.
How can I save the result as an image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scipy has an easy image save function! https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imsave.html

You should try this:

```
import scipy.misc
scipy.misc.imsave('mandelbrot.png',ns.eval())
```

I hope this works! Regardless, let me know!

Comment: works but scipy has a bug so you also need to `import scipy.misc`

Comment: PIL has an image save function. In fact, the example code calls it, but saves it into a bytesio object instead. You can just replace that with a filename ('mandelbrot.png' for instance) to save to a file. No new imports necessary.